# How to parse the svg `viewBox` attribute with a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I am a bit of a regular expression beginner and I'm trying to parse the `viewBox` attribute of an `<svg>` element using JavaScript.

The specs of a `viewBox` attribute looks like:

> > > The value of the ‘viewBox’ attribute is a list of four numbers <min-x>, <min-y>, <width> and <height>, separated by whitespace and/or a comma
> > >       https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

So in my understanding an attribute that looks like:
`viewBox="10 10.2, 80 80"` is valid.

I'm trying to build a regular expression that basically does:

```
viewBoxString = "10 10.2, 80 80";
[xmin, ymin, width, height] = parseViewBox(viewBoxString);
```

What does `function parseViewBox(viewBoxString) {...}` look like?

I tried to build this function by concatenating a regex that I found for a float and for the separator (an optional comma). But it doesn't yield a match...

```
function parseViewBox(viewBoxString) {
  float=/[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)/
  separator = /,?/
  pattern = float + separator + float + separator + float + separator + float
  return viewBoxString.match(pattern)
}
```

My desired output is:

```
xmin == 10, 
ymin == 10.2
width == 80
height == 80
```

But I don't know how to get there. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would use this regex: `(-?\d+\.?\d+,?\s?\,?){2}(\d+\.?\d+,?\s?\,?)\d+`

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use a regex, the DOM will provide all the numbers directly to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
function parseViewBox(viewBoxString, asNumbers = false) {
  let values = viewBoxString.split(/[ ,]/).filter(Boolean); // filter removes empty strings

  return asNumbers ? values.map(Number) : values;
}


let viewBoxString = "10 10.2, 80 80";
let [xmin, ymin, width, height] = parseViewBox(viewBoxString, true);
```

Comment: Ahh, circumventing the regex altogether, yeah, that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I think [Zim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57832322/636077) is probably better. More efficient, more readable, requires minimal error handling, looks less like a cat barfed on the keyboard.

```js
const {1: xmin, 2: ymin, 3: width, 4: height} = r.exec(input)
```

```js
const input = "10 10.2, 80 80";
const r = /(-?[0-9.]+)[\s,]+(-?[0-9.]+)[\s,]+(-?[0-9.]+)[\s,]+(-?[0-9.]+)/gi
const {1: xmin, 2: ymin, 3: width, 4: height} = r.exec(input) || {};

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = `xmin: ${xmin}, ymin: ${ymin}, width: ${width}, height: ${height}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Your regex is validating negative width and height :(

Comment: Haha, thanks! Yeah, regexes are quite easily akin to catbarf. But I'm still happy to see an answer to the original question, although circumventing it altogether is probably a lot more readable.